# Ajax call not sending to POST

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a function that includes an AJAX to send a JSON object retrieved from localStorage.  For some reason, in my PHP script, it never shows anything in the $_POST variable, despite me being pretty sure the AJAX call goes through successfully.  My code is as follows:

The javascript:

```
function processResults(){
      var finalResults = localStorage.getItem('results');
      finalResults = JSON.stringify(finalResults);

      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '../DB_add.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {'answers': finalResults},
        success: function(data){
          console.log(data);
          console.log('Success');
        }
      })
    }
```

The php script:

```
if(isset($_POST['answers'])){
$obj = json_decode($_POST['answers']);
print_r ($obj);
}
```

Any help as to why this isn't working would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you.

I've tried all of the options given so far, and nothing seems to be working.  I'm at a total loss.

For those asking, the finalResult variable is structured as:

```
[{"answer":0,"elapsed_time":1378,"stimulus_id":"8","task_id":1},{"answer":1,"elapsed_time":157,"stimulus_id":"2","task_id":1},{"answer":1,"elapsed_time":169,"stimulus_id":"1","task_id":1}, etc....
```

Comment: Take a look at your browser console (developers tools), under `network` and see more details about that request. Can you share the output?

Comment: The code looks good., is var ´finalResults` set ? try `console.log(finalResults);` and check it's content. I guess the problem starts there.

Comment: "pretty sure the AJAX call"  -- I would start by being sure.  then I would make sure that finalResults is good (see comment above)

Comment: I could be too that your POST is showing up, but gets turned to NULL by the json_decode. Can you print_r($_POST) at the first line instead? json_decode will fail silently and just return NULL when it finds an error.

Comment: I get a 200 OK response, and it shows the form data attached correctly.  It does show the type as text/html.  Would that make a difference?

Comment: @dgig I tried that, and it just posts and empty array.

Comment: try removing dataType: 'json', may it cause error because you already sending a data JSON.stringify(finalResults)

Comment: Why do you use `JSON.stringify` at all? Just send an object, `data` is converted to a query string, if not already a string.

Comment: you could use something like cURL to make sure your page is okay and can accept post data. not sure why it wouldn't but one more thing to cross off the list. *curl --data "answers=test_answers" http//example.com/DB_add.php*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dataType: 'json'` requires that what you output in PHP (`data` accepted in `success` section) must be valid json.

So valid json will be in PHP:

```
if(isset($_POST['answers'])){
    echo $_POST['answers'];
}
```

No need to decode it, it is json string already. No `var_dump`, no `print_r`

Answer (score -1):

I would remove the `dataType` property in your Ajax request and modify the structure of your data :

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '../DB_add.php',
    data: 'answers='&finalResults,
    success: function(data){
      console.log(data);
      console.log('Success');
    }
})
```

And in a second time I would test what I receive on PHP side :

```
if(isset($_POST['answers'])){
    var_dump(json_encode($_POST['answers']));
}
```

Comment: I tried this, and I received "success" in console.log, but nothing shows on the php side

Comment: Can you add an example of `finalResults`value you want to send ?

Answer (score -1):

Remove `dataType: 'json',` if you sending with `JSON.stringify`

JS.

```
function processResults(){
      var finalResults = localStorage.getItem('results');
      finalResults = JSON.stringify(finalResults);

      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '../DB_add.php',
        data: {'answers': finalResults},
        success: function(data){
          console.log(data);
          console.log('Success');
        }
      })
    }
```

PHP CODE:

```
if (!empty($_REQUEST['answers'])) {

$answers = json_decode(stripslashes($request['answers']));

var_dump($answers);

}
```

Comment: `dataType` has nothing to do with what you are sending.

Comment: The explanation given is a massive red herring that doesn't explain what the solution actually is.